# ESLint error: Failed to load 'eslint-plugin-jsdoc' in IntelliJ on Ubuntu - troubleshooting tips?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am struggling with ESLint not being able to load in IntelliJ 2023.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.

It seems like there are several syntax errors in the libraries, but I just could not belive that.

What could I do?

Best regards

Peter

PS: error in detail:

[image]

[image: pops up after each opening of a project]

If I correct this specific one (yes, I should not overwrite libraries, especially when I'm not an expert on that stuff), a new syntax error comes again.

Comment: Recent versions of `eslint-plugin-jsdoc` depend on Node 16 as a minimum version. Beyond merely updating your Node version, I would recommend using nvm (Node Version Manager) so that you can easily update Node versions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Node.js version do you have? Looks like it doesn't support the nullish coalescing operator; please make sure that the interpreter set up in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js** is v. 14 or higher, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing#browser_compatibility

Comment: Thank You! This was the solution. The global node version was right, it was 18.14.2. but the one in the IDE was not set up correctly.